# Converting Freecad files to python script

Tags: freecad

I have a set of FreeCAD files that I need to convert into Python scripts for automation purposes. What would be the most effective way to achieve this conversion? Are there any existing tools or libraries that can help with this task, or should I consider a specific approach for parsing and translating FreeCAD files into Python code?

Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!